# allowing * character in textbox C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am creating a rs232 dial pad in a WPF. The problem I am running into is with the star character. I don't know how to ask the question correctly because all I am getting results for are "password characters only".

Ultimately I'm trying to add the "*" programmatically. It does not matter if I used the keyboard or the virtual button. Whenever the character is added the program freezes. The debugger isn't pointing to anything and seems like its still waiting for instruction.

Any ideas?

Im adding the star with

```
textBox.text="*";
```

Comment: Is this just a standard `TextBox`? What event handlers are attached to this textbox? Are you actually sending the character to a device via RS-232?

Comment: Added to what? textBox?

Comment: it should work, there really shouldn't be a restriction on the * character. Try a different character or number and see if it still happens or try deleting the textbox, adding in a new one with a different name and try again. It should be working, so I'm really just throwing out ideas

Comment: Sorry I failed to mention that all I was working with a basic TextBox. @AyyappanSubramanian I only included that bit because thats all there was. That line repeated 10 times in 10 methods (one for each button) All but the one worked.

Answer (score -2):

Honestly I am not sure what happened. I started a new WPF and it worked. So i removed auto generated method all together and recreated it. Now it works. The entire method looked like this

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = "*";
    }
```

No clue but it works. Thank you for the replies

Comment: *I did nothing, but it miraculously started working* is not an answer that will be of any value or use to future readers here.

Comment: **minus 1** for such kind of poor answering.